# Sixth grade math (number related) problem

Tags: logic, education, rational-numbers

We have this statement (about rational numbers, btw):

If $m-n+p = p$ and $ m \neq n \neq 0$ then $ m = -n$

Is this true?
   a) always
   b) never
   c) sometimes

The given answer is b) but:
   1) this textbook often has some wrong answers and
   2) this question got me really thinking...

According to the truth table of the implication if the premise is false, then the whole implication is true, no matter what the conclusion is. 
In this case the premise is a conjunction of several facts, two of which are contradictory ($m = n $ and $m \neq n$). 
So the premise is false. And so I conclude the whole implication is true.
Then... what does that mean? I guess it means the correct answer is a).

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is a poorly worded math problem, sixth grade or otherwise. The statement

$$m \neq n \neq 0$$

is possibly meant to be something like

$$m, n \neq 0$$

instead. This would be to ensure that $m = n$ and $m = -n$ can't both be true simultaneously as it only occurs when $m = n = 0$.

This is only a guess, but it would mean the question would then be consistent with the textbook's provided answer.